# Dispatch group - cannot notify to main thread

Tags: swift, grand-central-dispatch, swift3

After reading Swift 3 evolution on GCD, I am trying to create dispatch group. The problem is the `group.notify(queue:` do not notify when I pass `DispatchQueue.main` as a queue, although it does work for background queue.

Also I am not sure my syntax is all correct, as I am trying to convert code from Swift 2 to Swift 3.

```
typealias CallBack = (result: Bool) -> Void
func longCalculations (completion: CallBack) {

let backgroundQ = DispatchQueue.global(attributes: .qosBackground)

    let group = DispatchGroup()  
    var fill:[Int] = [] 
    for item in 0...200 {
        group.enter() 
        if item > 50 {
            fill.append(item)
        }
        group.leave() 
    }

//Below in the notify argument If I pass `backgroundQ`, it seems to work correctly but not when DispatchQueue.main is passed.
```

**This code do not work**

```
group.notify(queue: DispatchQueue.main, execute: {
    completion(result: true)
    })
 }
```

**This works correctly**

```
group.notify(queue: backgroundQ, execute: {
    completion(result: true)
    })
 }
_______________________________________________________

longCalculations() { print($0) }
```

Comment: What's the code that _doesn't_ "work correctly"?

Comment: @matt, I have edited question for clarity, when I try to notify via `group.notify(queue: DispatchQueue.main, execute: {` the completion block return nothing(unable to print `Bool` value), where as when I pass a concurrent queue `backgroundQ`, the `Bool` value `true` is returned and printed correctly `longCalculations() { print($0) }`.

Comment: You're using `enter` and `leave` incorrectly. Might help you to read this article: http://amro.co/gcd-using-dispatch-groups-for-fun-and-profit

Answer (score 35, accepted):

After reading post suggested by Matt, I found that I was submitting task to main queue and when I asked to be notified on main thread itself, it got in the deadlock.

I have altered the code and now it is working as intended,

```
typealias CallBack = (result: [Int]) -> Void
func longCalculations (completion: CallBack) {
  let backgroundQ = DispatchQueue.global(attributes: .qosDefault)
  let group = DispatchGroup()

  var fill:[Int] = []
  for number in 0..<100 {
      group.enter()
      backgroundQ.async(group: group,  execute: {  
          if number > 50 {
            fill.append(number)
          }
          group.leave()

          })
      }

     group.notify(queue: DispatchQueue.main, execute: {
       print("All Done"); completion(result: fill)
     }) 
}

longCalculations(){print($0)}
```

Comment: Swift 4 -`let backgroundQ = DispatchQueue.global(qos: .default)` still `group.notify(queue: DispatchQueue.main, execute` not invokes. why?

Comment: can you share the link to Matt's post

Comment: This did the trick for me on Swift 5 as well.  Thanks!

Comment: For any one stumbling on this later, it might be better off to have all the enters up ahead before making the time consuming functions. Say you are making 5 APIs, have the 5 enters registered first, then make the first api call, that way you are safe. Any additional leave will cause a crash else.