# Dispatch Groups not working as expected

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, grand-central-dispatch

I set up a similar function to this and it works fine, however I'm crashing on `group.leave()` here, and in testing I noticed that 1 or 2 of the print lines `print("link = \(link)")` is being printed after `print("getRekos processing over, handler is called")`, in other words `group.leave()` is being called prior to full completion of the for loop or some of the iterations are "leaking" outside of the group.  What could be causing this?  I've posted the code for `getExpandedURL` and my custom extension `resolveWithCompletionHandler` which are used inside `getRekos`

```
 public func getRekos(rekoType: RekoCategory, handler: @escaping (Set<URL>) -> Void) {

        let setOfLinks = Set<URL>()
        let group = DispatchGroup() //Dispatch group code from: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38552180/dispatch-group-cannot-notify-to-main-thread
        let backgroundQ = DispatchQueue.global(qos: .default)


        TwitterRequest().fetchTweets(searchType: rekoType) { result in

            guard let tweets = TWTRTweet.tweets(withJSONArray: result) as? [TWTRTweet] else { print("error in getRekos casting TwitterRequest().fetchTweets result as [TWTRTweet]"); return }

            for tweet in tweets {

                let text = tweet.text

                group.enter()
                backgroundQ.async(group: group,  execute: {

                    //Check tweet text if contains any URLs
                    self.getExpandedURLsFromText(text: text, handler: { (getExpandedLinksResult, error) in

                        if error != nil {
                            group.leave()
                        } else {

                            for link in getExpandedLinksResult {
                                print("link = \(link)")

                            }
                            group.leave()
                        }
                    })
                })
            } //for tweet in tweets loop
            group.notify(queue: backgroundQ, execute: {
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    print("getRekos processing over, handler is called")
                    handler(setOfLinks)
                }
            })
        }
    }


private func getExpandedURLsFromText(text: String, handler: @escaping ([URL], Error?) -> Void) {

    var linksInText = [URL]()
    let group = DispatchGroup() //Dispatch group code from: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38552180/dispatch-group-cannot-notify-to-main-thread
    let backgroundQ = DispatchQueue.global(qos: .default)


    let types: NSTextCheckingResult.CheckingType = .link
    let detector = try? NSDataDetector(types: types.rawValue)

    guard let detect = detector else { print("NSDataDetector error"); return }

    let matches = detect.matches(in: text, options: .reportCompletion, range: NSMakeRange(0, (text.characters.count)))

    //CRITICAL CHECK - results were getting lost here, so pass back error if no match found
    if matches.count == 0 {
        handler([], RekoError.FoundNil("no matches"))
    }
        // Iterate through urls found in tweets
        for match in matches {

            if let url = match.url {

                    guard let unwrappedNSURL = NSURL(string: url.absoluteString) else {print("error converting url to NSURL");continue}

                    group.enter()
                    backgroundQ.async(group: group,  execute: {

                        //Show the original URL (ASYNC)
                        unwrappedNSURL.resolveWithCompletionHandler(completion: { (resultFromResolveWithCompletionHandler) in

                            guard let expandedURL = URL(string: "\(resultFromResolveWithCompletionHandler)") else {print("couldn't covert to expandedURL"); return}

                            linksInText.append(expandedURL)
                            group.leave()
                            //handler(linksInText, nil)
                        })
                    })


            } else { print("error with match.url") }
        } //for match in matches loop
            group.notify(queue: backgroundQ, execute: {
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    //print("getExpandedURLsFromText processing over, handler is called")
                    handler(linksInText, nil)
                }
            })
}

// Create an extension to NSURL that will resolve a shortened URL
extension NSURL
{
    func resolveWithCompletionHandler(completion: @escaping (NSURL) -> Void) {
        let originalURL = self
        let req = NSMutableURLRequest(url: originalURL as URL)
        req.httpMethod = "HEAD"

        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: req as URLRequest){body, response, error in

            if error != nil {
                print("resolveWithCompletionHandler error = \(error)")
            }

            if response == nil {
                print("resolveWithCompletionHandler response = nil")
            }
            completion(response?.url as NSURL? ?? originalURL)
            }
            .resume()
    }
}
```

Comment: The only thing I can spot is that you do not `return` after `handler([], RekoError.FoundNil("no matches"))`. So theoretically a second call to `handler(...)` could be placed. But should not in your case, as the `for match in matches` loop should not trigger.

Comment: Thanks, and I've tested and that block (i.e. `if matches.count == 0 {`) never fires, so I dont think that's it

Comment: Also note that there are multiple cases when `handler` is not called at all, therefore the group never notifies.

Comment: Where would `handler` not be called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there are multiple matches (`matches.count > 1`) in `getExpandedURLsFromText` then the result handler is called multiple times, making your dispatch group logic break up.

Clean up your logic.

You have to make sure that the completion handler is always called exactly once when successful and exactly once for each error. You are missing calls to completion handler in multiple places in your `guard` statements.

Comment: What do you recommend?  Using Dispatch Groups in `getExpandedURL` similarly to what I'm doing in `getRekos`?

Comment: @GarySabo That's one possibility, probably the easiest.

Comment: I updated my question using Dispatch Groups in `getExpandedURL`...this solves my original question in that it no longer crashes and now only notifies when every link has been iterated through, however the completion handler in `getExpandedURL` is still being called multiple times...any idea how I can structure my `.enter` and `leave` calls so that the handler is only called once?

Comment: @GarySabo Note that if there are no matches, then your `handler` is called once and then a second time from `notify`. You have to put a `return` after the first call.

Comment: Added, but I don't think that's the issue here as I never have no matches in my testing...still can't quite get the handler to get called only once?

Comment: @GarySabo Add a `print` statement to every call of your handler. You should find the problem quickly.

Comment: I actually think it's working fine, it's just being called multiple times since `getExpandedURL` is called multiple times (obviously, haha).  Appreciate the help!