# DispatchWorkItem not notifying main thread

Tags: swift, multithreading, grand-central-dispatch, swift-playground

Note: This is not duplicate question I have already seen [Dispatch group - cannot notify to main thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38552180/dispatch-group-cannot-notify-to-main-thread)

There is nothing answered about  **DispatchWorkItem**

I have code like below

```
let dwi3 = DispatchWorkItem {
    print("start DispatchWorkItem \(Thread.isMainThread)")
    sleep(2)
    
    print("end DispatchWorkItem")
}
let myDq = DispatchQueue(label: "A custom dispatch queue")
dwi3.notify(queue: myDq) {
    print("notify")

}
DispatchQueue.global().async(execute: dwi3)
```

Which is working correctly  (I can see notify on console) and not in main thread  **start DispatchWorkItem false**

> start DispatchWorkItem false
>
> end DispatchWorkItem
>
> notify

Now I am trying to notify to main thread using

```
dwi3.notify(queue: DispatchQueue.main) {
    print("notify")

}
```

But it never calls , I have read and found that if Thread is blocked then situation occurs. but i am already executing `DisptachWorkItem` in `DispatchQueue.global()`

Please Anyone can help me on this that what actually going on ?

[image]

Comment: Your code works for me with `dwi3.notify(queue: DispatchQueue.main)` in both a playground and in an app.  How are you running the code

Comment: It is strange I have just added code in playground but ` dwi3.notify(queue: DispatchQueue.main)` not  working !!

Comment: If you are running in a playground you must add `import PlaygroundSupport` and 
`PlaygroundPage.current.needsIndefiniteExecution = true`

Comment: @Paulw11 I have added screen shot

Comment: the `sleep(80)` will block the main queue.  Get rid of it and add the two lines from my previous comment.

Comment: @Paulw11 Thanks  after adding `import PlaygroundSupport and PlaygroundPage.current.needsIndefiniteExecution = true` now I can see `notify`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are running asynchronous code in a playground then you need to enable indefinite execution, otherwise execution may end before the callbacks execute.

Add the following lines to your code in the playground:

```
import PlaygroundSupport
PlaygroundPage.current.needsIndefiniteExecution = true
```

Once you do this, you will see that the notify executes correctly on the main queue.

Comment: Use `sleep` but no luck